# What is the recommended lowest fee for a segwit transaction when sending coins from a bc1 address?

Tags: transaction-fees, segregated-witness

What is the lowest fee for sending 1 btc from a segwit bc1 address?

Answer (score -1):

1000 satoshi for 1000 bytes

sorry, your question has no sence. the fee depends on network utilization.